# Problem with loading settings from .bashrc

Tags: bash, debian, bashrc

I have a strange problem with terminal settings. I am a Debian 3.16.7 user. 
I saw the `.bashrc` file using `ls -a` but I couldn't open it (no file comunicate), so I restored it from `/etc/skel/.bashrc.`

Now my .bashrc file looks ok but I can't source it. 
For example when I call `echo $HISTSIZE` I see `30` but in my .bashrc I have got `1000`.

Here is how my .bashrc file looks: http://pastebin.com/cYMY6rJj

after

```
 ls -a
```

I see:

```
toshiba% ls -a
.          .gnome2      .themes
..         .gnome2_private  .thumbnails
.adobe         .gnupg       .tmux
.bash_history  .gstreamer-0.10  .tmux.conf
.bash_logout   .gtk-bookmarks   .tmuxinator
.bashrc        .ICEauthority    Videos
.bat           .icons       .vim
.bin           .java        .vim-colortuner
.cache         jbus_client  .vim-cscope
.cgdb          .kde     .vim-fuf-data
.config        .local       .viminfo
.cscope.vim    .macromedia  .vimrc
.dbus          .mozilla     .vim-sessions
Desktop        Music        .vim-undo
.dircolors     .osd_conf    .w3m
Documents      Pictures     .wireshark
Downloads      .pip     workspace
.easystroke    .pki     .xfce4-session.verbose-log
eclipse        .profile     .xfce4-session.verbose-log.last
.face          Public       .zcache
.fonts         .PyCharm40   .zsh
.gconf         PycharmProjects  .zsh_compdump
.gdb           .recently-used   .zsh_history
.gitconfig     .ssh     .zshrc
.gksu.lock     .subversion
.gnome         Templates
```

My .profile file is empty. 
Please help.

Comment: It looks as if your shell is `zsh` not `bash`. What is the results of `echo $SHELL`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into the difference between login and non-login instances of bash. If bash is started as a login shell, it reads `.bash_profile`. If it is not started as a login shell, it reads `.bashrc`. You can easily check if this is the problem by starting another instance of bash from the command line (that is, just type `bash` and hit return) and see if your `.bashrc` settings take effect.

This is described in detail under the heading `INVOCATION` in the bash manual page.